# how to run this assembly code on nasm?

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, makefile, x86, nasm

I have a game source code but I could not assemble it on nasm , I could not understand where is the problem .

here is the makefile :

```
# Makefile for the nibbles game.

all: nibbles_asm nibbles_asm_start

# Rule for compiling C source
.c.o:
    gcc -Os -march=i686 -Wall -g -c $<

# Rule for compiling assembly source
.S.o:
    as -gstabs $^ -o $@



# ASM game
nibbles_asm: main.o nibbles.o helpers.o
    gcc -lcurses $^ -o -V $@

# ASM game
nibbles_asm_start: start.o nibbles.o helpers.o workaround.o
    gcc -lcurses -lc -nostdlib $^ -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *~
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f nibbles nibbles_asm
```

and here is the error :

```
as   -o nibbles.o nibbles.s
gcc -lcurses main.o nibbles.o helpers.o -o -V nibbles_asm
gcc: nibbles_asm: No such file or directory
make: *** [nibbles_asm] Error 1
```

it seems that as -gstabs $^ -o $@ do not build the nibbles_asm file ! 
I also typed the command by myself in terminal but it gave me alot of errors . my friend run this code on his computer , so the code does not have any problem .

Comment: pedantic remark: you can't run assembly on nasm. You run it on a CPU. You _assemble it_ with nasm

Comment: What the heck is the `-V` for ?

Comment: without -V it had this error : main.o: In function `main':
/home/aida/Desktop/13/main.c:45: undefined reference to `start_game'   and somebody told me to put it here to fix this

Comment: After the `-o` should be a filename.  If `-V` is needed, move it somewhere elsewhere--not between an option and the option value.

Comment: I moved -V here : gcc -V -lcurses $^ -o $@ and it did not build nibbles_asm but at least it could built nibbles_asm_start, please help why is like this ?! the whole assembly code did not assemble ! :(

Comment: what this error means ? gcc: error trying to exec 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc--lcurses': execvp: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no dependency to get from `nibbles.S` to `nibbles.o`.  Also, `helpers.o` and `workaround.o` don't have associated source file relations.  Add those relationship and it should work.

Comment: actually those relationship are there , $^ means  main.o nibbles.o helpers.o and  $@ = nibbles_asm

Comment: `nibbles_asm` appears to be the executable.  Note that this is Linux.

Comment: I change as -gstabs $^ -o $@ to as -gstabs main.o nibbles.o helpers.o -o nibbles_asm and again the same errors !

Answer (score 0):

You have a stray `-V` at the wrong place (as argument to `-o`) in your gcc command. Remove it or put it at the beginning.

Your second error `trying to exec 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc--lcurses': No such file` means that you are missing a space between gcc and -lcurses somewhere.